# Does auto complete work in command line mode(help command) in vim?

Tags: vim

Suppose that I am working in a vim buffer and would like to get help on a command that I heard/read about earlier but can't remember now the full name but can only recall the start of the name. Is it possible that vim helps in finding the command that I need to get help on? For example I type :h  and then type "colo" and press tab key , it should give me a bunch of choices to select from?

P:S: I am looking for a native vim solution and no plugin approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, this works

```
:h colo<Tab>
```

gives

```
:h :colo
```

with more `<Tab>` you can loop through the possibilities, with `<C-D>` you get a popup with all possibilities

Comment: Just discovered that you can move between the suggestions with <C-n> and <C-p> commands and use <CR> to select something.

Comment: What is the mnemonic for `<C-d>`?